# Convert numeric to string, keep decimal places in R

Tags: r, string, type-conversion, numeric, zero

I have a field that is being read as numeric, with values that look something like this: `"1234.00".` I would like to convert this to a string, but preserve the trailing zeroes after the decimal place.

When I use `as.character(1234.00)`, the result is `"1234"` instead of `"1234.00"`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One option is this `format(1234, nsmall = 2)`

Comment: @akrun I hope you didn't delete because of my comment; in fact your answer might be what the OP wants.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I think I misunderstood the question.  The OP is looking for getting the same format automatically as it is typed

Comment: this `sprintf("%.2f", c(1234.00, 150, 1, .03, .5))`?

Comment: @akrun i think your answer was exactly what the OP was looking for

Comment: @Parker Suppose if you have values `c(1234, 1234.00, 1234.000)`  How do you want the output to be ?

Comment: @akrun You're exactly right - values should be preserved exactly as typed.

Comment: If you have a field that's already being read as numeric, shouldn't it have already turned into "1234" instead of "1234.00"? If you meant that you have a field that you want to read in as numeric, can you not read as character instead? Or are the numbers supposed to be hardcoded?

Comment: @avid_useR I want to preserve the trailing zeroes. But you make a good point - in this case, I am reading in a CSV so I could specify the class upfront. Something like: read.csv('test.csv', colClasses=c("myfield"="character"))

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. Read in as character, and also convert as numeric if you need to do calculations.